# How do I get the sum of a column as a new row with column data

Tags: sql

There is a table with four columns:

```
SrNo Descript item1 item2 
1   | AA     | 45  | 25
2   | BB     | 25  | 51
3   | CC     | 41  | 22
```

I want get results like this:

```
SrNo| Descript| item1 |item2| totalitems
1   | AA      | 45    | 25  |  70
2   | BB      | 25    | 51  |  76
3   | CC      | 41    | 22  |  63
4   | Total   | 111   | 98  | 209
```

Comment: You can also try using an operator called rollup that will rollup the data to get you grand total with out using a union

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try;

```
select 
  SrNo, Descript, item1, item2, 
  item1+item2 as totalitems
from tbl
ORDER BY SrNo

union all

select  
  max(SrNo) + 1, 'Total', sum(item1), sum(item2), 
  sum(item1+item2) as totalitems
from tbl
```

Comment: Add ORDER BY SrNo at the end to ensure the correct result set order!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
select SrNo, Descript, item1, item2, item1+item2 as totalitems
from yourtable
Union all
select max(SrNo)+1, 'Total', sum(item1), sum(item2), sum(item1)+sum(item2) as totalitems
from yourtable
```

**Note :** If the data type of `item1` and `item2` is `varchar` then you may have to `cast` it to `int` before addititon

Comment: correct, it can get totalitems but how can i print SrNo 4 in same results set

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
drop table #t
create table #t(SrNo int, Descript varchar(10),item1 int,item2 int)
insert into #t values( 
1,'AA',45,25),
(2,'BB',25,51),
(3,'CC',41,22)


select  SrNo,Descript,item1,item2,item1+item2 as total into t6
from #t

select * from t6
union all

select 4,'Total',sum(item1),sum(item2),sum(total) from t6
```

### [fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/1610)

Comment: Two things are wrong. First syntax is not valid you need to select cte outside. second no. of column doesn't match

Comment: select 4 does just work with the sample data specified, but I suppose OP prefers a more generic solution...